# unable to parse bindings for nested knockout bindings

Tags: html, knockout.js

I created two sub divs inside main div and based on radio button selection, div is shown and hidden. Now , inside one of the sub div i created one dropdown and used foreach binding to populate it.Now when i am running , list of items are coming but show and hide functionality stopped working and in console it is shown as "unable to parse binding" of foreach.
    Kindly help me in resolving the issue.
    sample code is present below :

**HTML FILE**

```
<body>
<div id="selectdiv">
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radioGrp" />div1
    <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radioGrp" />div2
</div>
<div id="myDiv" name="myDiv"   class="myDiv" style="font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 12pt; border: 1px solid black;">
  <div id="subDiv1" name="subDiv1"  data-bind="visible:subDiv1" class="subDiv1" style="color: #FF0000; border: 1px dotted black;">
    <h5>Section 1</h5>
    <p>MONTHS...</p>
    <div id="tabContainer">
        <ul data-bind="foreach: months">
            <li>
                <b data-bind="text: $data"></b>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>  
  </div>
  <br />
  <div id="subDiv2" name="subDiv2"  data-bind="visible:subDiv2" class="subDiv2" style="color: #FF00FF;border: 1px dashed black;">
    <h5>Section 2</h5>
    <p>This paragraph would be your content paragraph...</p>
    <p>Here's another content article right here.</p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

**JS FILE**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("ready");
    var divdispalyViewModel1 = { 
        subDiv1: ko.observable(true)
    };
    var divdispalyViewModel2 = { 
        subDiv2: ko.observable(true)
    };
    ko.applyBindings({
        months:[ 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'etc' ]
    });
   // alert("ready2");
    ko.applyBindings(divdispalyViewModel1);
    ko.applyBindings(divdispalyViewModel2);    
    $('#radio1').click(function () { 
        alert("radio 1");
        divdispalyViewModel1.subDiv1(true);
        divdispalyViewModel2.subDiv2(false);

    });
    $('#radio2').click(function () { 
        alert("radio2");
        divdispalyViewModel1.subDiv1(false);
        divdispalyViewModel2.subDiv2(true);

    });
 });
```

---

```
Month list is fetched from method present in second javascript but how html will get to know that month is binded to second javascript...i mean to say, suppose my first javascript is like below :              $(document).ready(function() {
alert("ready");
    var vm = function () {
        var self = this;
        self.subDiv1 = ko.observable(false);
        self.subDiv2 = ko.observable(false);
        var subDemoMainObj=new subDemoMain();
        subDemoMainObj.getMonths();
        //self.months = ko.observableArray(['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'etc']);
    };
    ko.applyBindings(new vm());
    ko.applyBindings(subDemoMainObj, $('#tabContainer')[0]);
 });                                                                 Second javascript is as below                                          function(ko){

alert("ready1");
    var getMonths = function () {
        var self = this;
        self.months = ko.observableArray(['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'etc']);
    };

    // alert("ready2");
    //ko.applyBindings(new getMonths());`enter code here`
},                                                                    i am expecting something like this but not understanding where i am going wrong :( 
:(
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all calling applyBinding multiple times is wrong. There should be only one call per element and since you are not passing any element parameter it will be bound to body.
2. if you are using multiple view models you need to use `with` biding to pick that vm however in your case you dont need those view models (divdispalyViewModel1 & divdispalyViewModel2)
3. Then you dont need to handle the click event and change the values of the subDiv1, this is exactly what ko addresses.

in all this is how you could do it

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("ready");
    var vm = function () {
        var self = this;
        self.subDiv1 = ko.observable(false);
        self.subDiv2 = ko.observable(false);

        self.months = ko.observableArray(['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'etc']);
    };

    // alert("ready2");
    ko.applyBindings(new vm());

});
```

html:

```
<body>
    <div id="selectdiv">
        <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radioGrp" value='div1' data-bind="checked:subDiv1" />div1
        <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radioGrp" value='div2' data-bind="checked:subDiv1" />div2</div>
    <div id="myDiv" name="myDiv" class="myDiv" style="font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 12pt; border: 1px solid black;">
        <div id="subDiv1" name="subDiv1" data-bind="visible:subDiv1()=='div1'" class="subDiv1" style="color: #FF0000; border: 1px dotted black;">
             <h5>Section 1</h5>

            <p>MONTHS...</p>
            <div id="tabContainer">
                <ul data-bind="foreach: months">
                    <li> <b data-bind="text: $data"></b>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div id="subDiv2" name="subDiv2" data-bind="visible:subDiv1()=='div2'" class="subDiv2" style="color: #FF00FF;border: 1px dashed black;">
             <h5>Section 2</h5>

            <p>This paragraph would be your content paragraph...</p>
            <p>Here's another content article right here.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Your drop down doesn't work, that's different issue (css?)

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhanasekaran/WNkMV/)

Comment: The `months` property can just be an ordinary array since it's never going to change.

Comment: @Dhana..Thanks alot for the solution. I have one more doubt,as i need to implement one scenario in my project and i am new to knockout js, so please help me. Suppose i am getting the value of months from some method in other javascript and that method is being called from the above javascript method vm. In such scenario , how to pass the value of months and bind it to html.

Comment: If you mean the months list is fetched by calling a method, you only need to push those values in the months observableArray. The view will update. Have a read through knockout docs, there is enough examples to understand observableArrays and rest.

Comment: Since my query is coming as too long , i am unable to put into comments.so i have put into "add another answer" section.

Comment: @DhanaKrishnasamy As you told that there should be one binding per element , i tried in that way also but its not working.Can you please suggest where i am going wrong , i'll be highly greatful to you. JSFiddle link is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SMySE/1/)

Comment: Hint: Your code has errors and you are not using ko to handle all the things possible (like binding check box values).

Comment: @ Dhana..Sorry if am sounding dumb but i unable to understand your hint.i am not using checkbox in the shared fiddle link [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SMySE/1/).

Comment: @Dhana..i'll be highly greatful if you can throw some light on this scenario also mentioned in this link : [Scenario](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19494132/how-to-pass-value-in-knockout-js)

Comment: Sorry, I'm caught up with busy release schedule, will try to answer you as soon as I get free time. Btw if you take a look at ko live examples and tutorials if will help as well

Comment: I read those examples twice but when it comes to implementation part i faced alot of issue :( :(